# unlocking excel file exported from javaFX Desktop App

Tags: file, javafx, export

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555883/locking-and-unlocking-files-using-the-java-api)
I know this post is old,I'm having the same issue with excel file. My scenario is: I have a Desktop app written in javaFX the user export a TableView content into an excel file. Everything goes fine except when the file tries to open the message of the file is locked by user for editing.
How do I force or work around to unlock the file from the App that generate it?
This was my initial code

```
String directory = CreateDir();
        if (rs != null) {
           File file_excel = new File(directory + "\\" + reportName + ".xls");
                file_excel.createNewFile();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    pc.exportToXls_File(sql, uID, uPW, file_excel);
                }
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file_excel);
            }
```

exportToXls_File Function

```
public void exportToXls_File(String sql, String userName, String passWord, File fileName)
            throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent();
        DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection();
        conn = dbc.getConnection(event, userName, passWord);
        try {
            try (
                    /**
                     * Create new Excel workbook and sheet
                     */
                    HSSFWorkbook xlsWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook()) {

                HSSFSheet xlsSheet = xlsWorkbook.createSheet();
                short rowIndex = 0;
                /**
                 * Execute SQL query
                 */
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                /**
                 * Get the list of column names and store them as the first Row
                 * of the spreadsheet.
                 */
                ResultSetMetaData colInfo = rs.getMetaData();
                List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<>();
                HSSFRow titleRow = xlsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);

                for (int i = 1; i <= colInfo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    colNames.add(colInfo.getColumnName(i));
                    titleRow.createCell((int) (i - 1)).setCellValue(
                            new HSSFRichTextString(colInfo.getColumnName(i)));
                    xlsSheet.setColumnWidth((int) (i - 1), (short) 4000);
                }
                /**
                 * Save all the data from the database table rows
                 */
                while (rs.next()) {
                    HSSFRow dataRow = xlsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
                    int colIndex = 0;
                    for (String colName : colNames) {
                        dataRow.createCell(colIndex++).setCellValue(
                                new HSSFRichTextString(rs.getString(colName)));
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * Write to disk
                 */
                xlsWorkbook.write(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
                xlsWorkbook.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
            out.println(ex);
        } finally {

            if (conn != null) {
                stmt.close();
                closeConnection((OracleConnection) conn);
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: And the issue you get is what exactly? How does the problem manifest? The way you write to the file seems to be a) very inefficient since you're reading and writing the file for every single db row or b) you never close the file which means you're creating the issue yourself. Usually the code would look something like this: `Document doc = createNewInMemoryDoc(); while (rs.next()) { addRowToDoc(doc, rs);} saveToFile(doc, file_excel); Desktop....` and usually `createNewFile` is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you fabian for the quick answer. I included the exportToXls_File  function that will give the whole picture.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by `createNewInMemoryDoc()`, `addRowToDoc(doc, rs)` and `saveToFile(doc, file_excel)`;

Comment: You're doing the export for each row in some `ResultSet` but on second look you don't seem to use pass any info from the resultset to the `exportToXls_File` method. I just wanted to demonstrate the usual approach in general, which would be: 1. initialize the document data structure 2. fill datastructure with info using a loop 3. write data to output file...

Comment: The file is getting created and data is written to it. The issue I'm having the application locks the file and prevent it from opening.

Comment: The system messages says `the file xxx is  locked for editing by ...userName  of the machine`. I can open the file in `Read Only` Mode and save it with different name. I'm trying to save these steps.